How can a solution template be created for a .Net 8 solution that has multiple projects iwhere each project already has .template.config?
I am trying to create one template nuget package for a .Net 8 solution.  The solution has 5 projects within it (all are .Net 8).
All the projects have a .template.config director with .template.json files.  I can create project template Nuget files with this.
I am trying to understand how I can create one solution template nuget.  All the documentation I have seen requires me to create a .template.config directory at the solution file level and create one template.json file for the solution and then create a .csproj file to use for the Nuget creation.
If I have to create one template.json file, how do I put project specific items in it?  Can it relate to the other .template.json files for each project?
There is so little documentation.

Hi,@Mike Lenart.  You can create a solution template for a .NET 8 solution with multiple projects by organizing project templates within the solution template directory structure, each with its own .template.config directory and template.json file.
SolutionTemplate/
├── .template.config/
│   └── template.json    (Solution template metadata)
├── Project1/
│   ├── Project1.csproj
│   └── .template.config/
│       └── template.json   (Project template metadata)
├── Project2/
│   ├── Project2.csproj
│   └── .template.config/
│       └── template.json   (Project template metadata)
└──

You could also refer to Create multi-project templates to see if it helps

@HuiLiu-MSFT Thanks. Are you saying to have a .template.config folder within each project directory and a .tempate.config directory in the solution folder?  If so, that is what I have.  Also referring to that link you provided, that states it doesn’t work when using the dotnet new command and that is what we use.

I summarized the response. You could check it out.

You could create a solution template for a .NET 8 solution with multiple projects by organizing project templates within the solution template directory structure, each with its own .template.config directory and template.json file.
SolutionTemplate/
├── .template.config/
│ └── template.json (Solution template metadata)
├── Project1/
│ ├── Project1.csproj
│ └── .template.config/
│ └── template.json (Project template metadata)
├── Project2/
│ ├── Project2.csproj
│ └── .template.config/ │
└── template.json (Project template metadata)
└──
You could also refer to Create multi-project templates to see if it helps.
Update:
I think you are on the right track.
Regarding the dotnet new command not working as expected, there may be some compatibility issues or limitations when using solution templates with the dotnet new command.You may need to ensure that your template metadata files (template.json) are correctly configured and that your template files are structured as expected. Additionally, make sure you're using the appropriate command options and arguments when invoking dotnet new.
